# On using Lingua-TreeTagger-0.06

Tags: perl, nlp, treetagger

I am very, very new to NLP and the like. Therefore, I have a very basic question. I want to POS-tag an corpus of files with TreeTagger using a `Mac OSX 10.6.8`. I have installed `TreeTagger` by using the instructions provided at http://www.cis.uni-muenchen.de/~schmid/tools/TreeTagger/

[*I installed it in /Applications*]

Then I have installed `Lingua-TreeTagger-0.06` for '*for calling the TreeTagger and manipulating its output*'. This took a lot of effort to do.

[*I installed it in /Applications*]

I think I have succeeded in the previous steps. Now what? I mean how do I call Tree-Tagger?

Thanks to anybody who could help me?

mc

Comment: have you followed the instructions? where are your problems? You just call it like any other command line program. From within the installation directory, you do `cmd/tree-tagger-‹your language›-utf8 < ‹your text file›`.

Comment: Thanks Patrick. Your answer got me on the right track.

Comment: I think this could be closed or something. rtfm, but it is still in unanswered questions.

Answer (score 0):

Lingua::TreeTagger is a Perl module that is useful only if you want to use TreeTagger from within a Perl script. Examples of how to do so are given in [the module's online documentation](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Lingua-TreeTagger/lib/Lingua/TreeTagger.pm). Otherwise you should call the tree-tagger application from the terminal as commented by Patrick J.S. above (unless you are on Windows, where [a user-friendly graphical interface](http://www.smo.uhi.ac.uk/~oduibhin/oideasra/interfaces/winttinterface.htm) is available).